# Java container .contains question

Tags: java, containers, contains

Is there an easy way to check a container if it contains a value, not an object? This is the code I'd like to work:

```
String[] i = {"One", "Two", "Three"};

if (Arrays.asList(i).contains("One")){
return true;
}
```

Is there a way to do this or will I have to loop through the array myself?

Comment: I copied it verbatim and it worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That should work fine.  A String is an object, so you can use the [`contains(Object)`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17476_01/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29) overload (which is based on `equals`).

Comment: I guess it makes sense that `contains()` uses `.equals` instead of `==`. I think I'm just over thinking this.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried that code? It should work.

Java collections use `equals` to determine `contains` equality. Thus if the `equals` method on an object tests for value (rather than reference) equality, what you want will work.

Strings check to see if their values are the same.

Answer (score 1):

```
class ContainsTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] i = {"One", "Two", "Three"};
        System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.asList(i).contains("One"));
    }  
}
```

OUTPUT

```
 ----jGRASP exec: java ContainsTest

true

 ----jGRASP: operation complete.
```

I'd say it works.

Answer (score 0):

To repeat everybody else, String *is* an object, so this will work fine.  The contains() method uses Object.equals() to determine whether the given object exists in the list.